# Regular rings, semiregular rings, perfect rings, semiperfect rings

Tags: ring-theory

I'm pretty sure that this is not the appropriate place to ask such question, but unfortunately I don't know other communities to ask there. I just want somebody to recommend me a book that gives a solid understanding of the notions of "**regular rings** (*Von Neumann ring*)", "**semiregular rings**", "**perfect rings**", and "**semiperfect rings**". I'm new to all these notions, so I'll be grateful if the recommended book is suitable for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A book that covers all of these topics *except semiregular rings* is T.Y. Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings*.

Another book that covers perfect and semiperfect rings is Anderson and Fuller's *Rings and categories of modules*.

A hugely useful book on von Neumann regular rings is Goodearl's *Von Neumann regular rings*.  It does not cover semireuglar rings, though.

I think maybe the most information on semiregular rings in one place would be in Tuganbaev's *Rings close to regular*.

Comment: I forgot there are also sometimes attached references for ring properties at the DaRT:  [perfect](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/82/), [semiperfect](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/25/),  [VNR](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/14/), [semiregular](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/50/)